# Convert from coordinates to pixels

Tags: coordinates, pixel

I am implementing a rightclick context menu on my google v3 map and I need to get the pixel x and y to correctly position the menu. I get the lat and the lng, anyone have a nice solution to get the pixel x and y?

Best Regards

Henkemota

Comment: Can you provide code what you are doing right now? Also, what language is this in?

Answer (score 0):

```
index=x+(y*height)

x = index % width
y = index / height
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the above answer:

```
index=x+(y*width)
```

//(not y*height ... because you're taking one full horizontal line of pixels (e.g. 1280px) and multiplying that by the number of lines (y) down the screen at which x is, then adding x to account for x pixels over in the next full line.)

```
x = index % width
y = index / height
```