# Convert canvas coordinates to pixels

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to convert the xy coordinates of angry birds online, but I can't figure out how to calculate y coordinate!

Here is the data from the game:
http://120403-1305-dot-latest-dot-project-slingshot-hr.appspot.com/fowl/json/Level1-1.json

the x coordinate is calculated by x - item width / 2, and every object gets the right left position.

I can't figure out how to calculate the y coord to pixels.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:
I use this to find the coordinates of a pixel, I guess it will work with angry birds too ;)

y = index / height

check out my answer here:
[Convert from coordinates to pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917326/convert-from-coordinates-to-pixels/13044662#13044662)